# How to display AM/PM on text in swiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment

I've inserted an timer, so the time changes according to the system clock. the problem is, its displaying in numbers without am/pm like(12:33). please guide me to solve this problem.

This is the code I used to display the text.

```
@State var endTime = Date()
var body: some View {
Text("Ends - \(myViewModel.timeString(date: endTime))")
 .onAppear(perform: {let _ = self.updatedEndTime})
}
```

This is code I used to update timer according to the system time.

```
var updateEndTime: Timer {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0, repeats: true,
       block: {_ in
        self.endTime = Date() + myViewModel.player.duration - myViewModel.player.currentTime
          })
    }
```

My view model code

```
var timeFormat: DateFormatter {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    return formatter
}

func timeString(date: Date) -> String {
     let time = timeFormat.string(from: date)
     return time
}
```

Comment: Please provide your view model `timeString` function

Comment: please check the edited question

Comment: the question is closed linking to another question, but questions are no the same so i ll put my answer as a comment !

Comment: @State var endTime = Date()
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(endTime, style: .time)
    }

Comment: there is a another initialiser in Text to work with Date()..check above comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `amSymbol` and `pmSymbol` on `DateFormatter` and use the `a` symbol to print it.

```
lazy var timeFormat: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
        formatter.amSymbol = "AM"
        formatter.pmSymbol = "PM"
        return formatter
}()
```

In my locale (US), even without setting `amSymbol` and `pmSymbol`, they appear as "AM"/"PM", but I'm not sure that's true across all locales.

Comment: its expensive creating DateFormatter every time whenever a time need!

Comment: Updated to make it lazy init. Note that the original was just adjusting OP’s code.

Comment: @jnpdx it decreases the performance. Better way is to use the solution which I have commented in the question .(since this question is closed )

Comment: Calling it once with lazy will not decrease performance. Your way works as well, but is ultimately less flexible if a more custom format is needed.